# getting python executable or running on the web

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I currently have a python script that runs on my local machine windows 7. I am using the following

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
import ctypes
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os, fnmatch
from scipy.signal import argrelextrema
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib import colors
from reportlab.lib.units import mm, inch
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A3, A4,landscape,letter, inch,portrait
from reportlab.platypus import Image
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Table, TableStyle, Image, Paragraph
import subprocess
import sys
```

getting an executable is a challenge. Even If I do there are all these .dll files and dependencies. Now I am thinking how difficult it would be to get my code to run on the web? Or do I abandon python and go for something else like java, C#, Delphi or ? A Gui would be nice to have since currently it is console driven. My program goes as follows. A user enters something then the program will calculate something report back to the user. Then the user will enter another parameter and the program will calculate something else. A table and graph is produced but the graph is not necessary.
The goal is to make it simple for the user to use.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried to make an executable? I'm sure you'll get it running as expected using pyinstaller or cx_Freeze, they're easy to use and powerful.

Comment: try using something like django and import your code, should be pretty easy to get it on the web

Comment: I'd say django is more learning curve than using a simple Python CGI script.

Answer (score 0):

See using [Python on the web](https://docs.python.org/3.3/howto/webservers.html). From your imports it looks complicated enough to warrant doing it on the backend (server side). So I recommend sticking with Python.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get an executable using cx_Freeze (cx_Freeze-4.3.4-cp27-none-win_amd64). I am using python 2.7.9. I used the following setup.py script

```
import cx_Freeze
import Tkinter as Tk
import ctypes
import numpy
import matplotlib
import os, fnmatch
import sys
import subprocess
import reportlab

base = None

if sys.platform == 'win32':
    base = "Win32GUI"

executables = [
    cx_Freeze.Executable("Test.py", base=base),
]

cx_Freeze.setup(
    name = "Testv1.0",
    options = {"build_exe":{"packages":["Tkinter", "matplotlib"], "includes":["FileDialog"], "excludes":[]}},
    version = "0.1",
    description = "MyApp",
    executables = executables
)
```

Now what was key was adding "matplotlib" inside "packages":["Tkinter", "matplotlib"] and also having "includes":["FileDialog"], in the options. This resolved any errors I was having while trying to create the .exe.